# Git tagging: on the merge-commit or the commit?

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a situation where a feature branch (call it feature-A) wasn't merged on master for a very long time, so long in fact that another feature branch (feature-B) was merged during that time.

Normally, I tag the merge-commit in master that represents the point at which it became a new version.

However, in my case above, if I tag the merge-commit for feature-A then the changes for feature-B *and* feature-A changes will be included in the tag. This doesn't seem right, which made me wonder that maybe I should be tagging the *commits* and not the merges.

Googling (and stackoverflow) didn't yield many opinions either way, but I'm probably using the wrong terms.

Is there a best practice for tagging commits vs merge-commits?

Comment: A merge commit is a commit, so I have no idea what you're trying to say here.

Comment: It's not really clear what your tags are intended to be. A version _always_ has previous work on it, and branches are often merged in an order different from creation order. Why is that a problem? That said, "best practice" in Git is mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: @isherwood Yea, the tags are for versioning. The feature-A represents version 1.0 and feature-B represents version 2.0. In my case, version 1.0 was merged in after version 2.0. This isn't really a problem like you indicated, but now if I tag the merge-commit for version 1.0 it will include 2.0 changes as well. Doesn't seem right, which made me wonder if I should be tagging commit-commits (or whatever they are called) instead of merge-commits.

Comment: Tag the commit from which you perform release.

Comment: @phd Yeah, that's where I screwed up. I deployed from a different branch and I also wasn't tagging back then.

Comment: If you deployed from a different branch, then just tag the version you deployed from on that branch. As phd said, tag what you released. If you tag anything else than the commit you actually released, or deployed from, then that tag is pretty much useless.

Comment: And I would even go as far as claiming that you didn't *really* screw up. Sure, it's a bit messy that you didn't merge before releasing, but in the end, when you finally do merge, that commit you released from will still be in the history, so all will be fine.